# React ref is only updating one instance

Tags: javascript, reactjs, refs

Got an interesting problem withs refs.

I'm mapping over a component and rendering it multiple times and passing a ref to each one

```
const ref = useRef()

{data.map(d) => (
  <Component
    {...lotsOfOtherProps}
    ref={ref}
  />
)}
```

Then in a grandchild component I have:

```
  const anotherRef = React.useRef()
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    reset: () => {
      anotherRef?.current.reset()
    },
  }))
```

In this component I have a button and when I toggle it I call

`anotherRef?.current?.reset()` and this works and does what I want

but I'm wondering when I click a "reset all" button, how I can get all the refs to reset?

Comment: *"...and passing a ref to each one."* You're passing **the same** ref to each one. A ref can only hold **one** value, so you're just overwriting it each time. If you want a ref for every one of those, you'll need a ref for everyone of those, not just one. I haven't used `useImperativeHandle` so can't post a solution, but that's the problem. (I would probably try to find some other way to solve it, though, rather than [imperative code using refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle).)

Answer (score 1):

You are replacing the ref with each iteration and finally assigning it to the last element. You need to create an array of refs.

```
const refs = [];

{
  data.map((d, index) => {
    const newRef = React.createRef();
    refs[index] = newRef;
    return <Component {...lotsOfOtherProps} ref={newRef} />;
  });
}
```

`refs` will contain the array of ref for each component created from `data` array.